# SWT Table with date chooser fields

Tags: java, date, swt, editor

This is an obvious question but for some reason I haven't found a solution that works. I have a table with 3 columns, the first two are dates, the third one I'm using a Spinner because I want the user to only enter numbers. I need all fields to be editable, but

- the field should be editable only when it's in focus, when it's clicked on
- the other fields in the same row should not be editable
- when the field loses focus, it should go back to "default" mode

These are all normal things that one would expect in an editable table. For some reason I couldn't make this work in SWT. Right now what I have is:

1. I add a new row, all fields are "default"
2. I click on the row, all fields turn into editable (the date fields become combo boxes etc.)
3. after the row losing focus, it remains editable

This is the code that I have right now, it's based on some other code I found on the internet:

```
// this will happen when you click on the table
table.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
        // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        // Clean up any previous editor control
        final TableEditor editor1 = new TableEditor(table);               
        // The editor must have the same size as the cell and must
        // not be any smaller than 50 pixels.
        editor1.horizontalAlignment = SWT.LEFT;
        editor1.grabHorizontal = true;
        editor1.minimumWidth = 50;
        Control oldEditor = editor1.getEditor();
        if (oldEditor != null)
            oldEditor.dispose();                

        // Identify the selected row 
        TableItem item = (TableItem)e.item;
        if (item == null) return;

        // this is the editor for the first column
        DateTime startDateTxt = new DateTime(table, SWT.BORDER | SWT.DROP_DOWN | SWT.LONG);
        startDateTxt.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                DateTime text = (DateTime)editor1.getEditor();
                editor1.getItem().setText(0, new LocalDate(text.getYear(), text.getMonth(), text.getDay()).toString());
            }
        });
        editor1.setEditor(startDateTxt, item, 0);

        // and now comes the editor for the 2nd column
        //~~~~
        // Clean up any previous editor control
        final TableEditor editor2 = new TableEditor(table);               
        // The editor must have the same size as the cell and must
        // not be any smaller than 50 pixels.
        editor2.horizontalAlignment = SWT.LEFT;
        editor2.grabHorizontal = true;
        editor2.minimumWidth = 50;
        oldEditor = editor2.getEditor();
        if (oldEditor != null)
            oldEditor.dispose();                

        // this is the editor for the second column
        DateTime endDateTxt = new DateTime(table, SWT.BORDER | SWT.DROP_DOWN | SWT.LONG);
        endDateTxt.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                DateTime text = (DateTime)editor2.getEditor();
                editor2.getItem().setText(1, new LocalDate(text.getYear(), text.getMonth(), text.getDay()).toString());
            }
        });
        editor2.setEditor(endDateTxt, item, 1);

        //~~~~
        // Clean up any previous editor control
        final TableEditor editor3 = new TableEditor(table);               
        // The editor must have the same size as the cell and must
        // not be any smaller than 50 pixels.
        editor3.horizontalAlignment = SWT.LEFT;
        editor3.grabHorizontal = true;
        editor3.minimumWidth = 50;
        oldEditor = editor3.getEditor();
        if (oldEditor != null)
            oldEditor.dispose();                

        // this is the editor for the third column
        Spinner percentTxt = createNewSpinner(table, SWT.NONE);
        percentTxt.addModifyListener(new ModifyListener() {
            public void modifyText(ModifyEvent me) {
                Spinner text = (Spinner)editor3.getEditor();
                editor3.getItem().setText(2, text.getText());
            }
        });  
        editor3.setEditor(percentTxt, item, 2);   
        //~~~~

    }
});
```

As you can see, when the user clicks on the table, I get the current row, and add 3 editors to the row. What I would like to do is get the selected column. I haven't found how to do this. If I get the selected column, then I would be able to create an editor just for the selected cell, and not the whole row.

I also haven't figured out how to dispose the editor after it loses focus. If the user clicks outside the table, then it has clearly happened. But what if the user just clicks on another cell? Then I would have to dispose the old editor and create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

To get the selected column you can call `TableItem.getBounds(columnIndex)` for each column and see if the selection is within the rectangle returned.